# TypeError with Python

Tags: twitterapi-python

I'm just learning Python, and I'd be grateful for any help. When running the below code, I receive a message that says: "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable".

How can I fix this?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import sys

class TwitterBot:
    def __init__(self,username,login):
        self.username = username
        self.login = login
        self.bot = webdriver.Safari()

def login(self):
        bot = self.bot
        bot.get('https://twitter.com/')
        time.sleep(3)
        email = bot.find_element_by_class_name('email-input')
        login = bot.find_element_by_name('session[login]')
        email.clear()
        login.clear()
        email.send_keys(self.username)
        login.send_keys(self.login)
        login.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        time.sleep(3)

auto = TwitterBot('email', 'password')
auto.login()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here. The first has to do with your formatting. Because `def login(self):` isn't indented, it isn't a method of your `TwitterBot` class. The second issue is that you already have a member variable of the class called `login`, so you'll have a name conflict.

You're getting a `TypeError` because you're trying to call the string `login` like a method.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import sys

class TwitterBot:
    def __init__(self,username,login_credential):
        self.username = username
        self.login_credential = login_credential
        self.bot = webdriver.Safari()

    def login(self):
        bot = self.bot
        bot.get('https://twitter.com/')
        time.sleep(3)
        email = bot.find_element_by_class_name('email-input')
        login = bot.find_element_by_name('session[login]')
        email.clear()
        login.clear()
        email.send_keys(self.username)
        login.send_keys(self.login_credential)
        login.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        time.sleep(3)

auto = TwitterBot('email', 'password')
auto.login()
```